# How to get the sums of data in between dates in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hello guys how can i do this correct with no error?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_per_transaction
    @Datefrom DATETIME,
    @Dateto DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        Trans,
        SUM (ISNULL(DI_SC,0)) AS "Sum of  SC",
        SUM (ISNULL(DI_PWD,0)) AS "Sum of  PWD",
        SUM (ISNULL(DI_Student,0)) AS "Sum of  Student",
        SUM (ISNULL(VATable,0)) AS "Sum of  VATable",
        SUM (ISNULL(VAT,0)) AS "Sum of  VAT",
        SUM (ISNULL(VATExempt,0)) AS "Sum of  VATExempt",
        SUM (ISNULL(GrossAmount,0)) AS "Sum of  GrossAmount"
    FROM [ATIBTicketingDB_test2].[dbo].[Transaction]

    WHERE BETWEEN DatePosted  @Datefrom AND @Dateto

    GROUP BY Trans;

END
```

edited: this is my error- WHERE BETWEEN DatePosted  @Datefrom AND @Dateto

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you some sample data and expected results handy?

Comment: LordBaconPants when i add this  WHERE BETWEEN DatePosted  Datefrom AND Dateto i get an error

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s that's noted, thanks for the advice :D

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause should be:

```
WHERE DatePosted BETWEEN @Datefrom AND @Dateto
```

not

```
WHERE BETWEEN DatePosted  @Datefrom AND @Dateto
```